# Given an element $ \ (a,b) \in A \ $ describe its equivalence class $ \ [(a,b)] \ $ geometrically

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider the horizontal strip $ \ A=\{(x,y): \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \ and \ \ -1 \leq y \leq 1 \} \ $.

Define a relation $ \ \sim \ $ on $ \ A \ $ by $ \ (a,b) \sim (c,d) \ $ iff  $ \ a-c \in \mathbb{Z} \ $ and $ \ d=(-1)^{a-c} c \ $ .

This relation is an $ \ equivalence \ \ relation \ $

Then answer the following questions:

$ \ (i) \ $ Given an element $ \ (a,b) \in A \ $ describe its equivalence class $ \ [(a,b)] \ $ geometrically

$ (ii) \ $ What is $ \ A / \sim \ $ topologically ?

**Answer:**

$ (i) \ $

Since $ a-c \in \mathbb{Z} \ $ , we conclude that

$ d=0 \ \ or \ \ d=c \ \ or \ \ d=-c \ $

Thus $ [(a,b)]=\{(c,0), (c,c) , (c,-c) \} \ $

Further $ -1 \leq d \leq 1 \ $

Thus the equivalence class contains the sets $ \ \{(x,y): -1 \leq x \leq 1 , \ y=0 \} , \ \{(x,y): -1 \leq x \leq 1 ,\ y=x \} , \ \{(x,y): -1 \leq x \leq y , \ y=-x\} \ $

Thus geometrically $ \ [(a,b)] \ $ represents the following graph

[image]

$ (ii) \ $

**I think $ \ A / \sim \ $ is a quotient space**  .

**But I can not describe it.**

**Help me out in the both questions.**

Comment: The relation is not reflexive (hence is not an equivalence relation). E.g. we do not have $(1,0)\sim(1,0)$.

Comment: are you sure that it's not $d = (-1)^{a-c} b$ instead ?

Comment: ok may be $ d=(-1)^{a-c}b \ $ . But it is given that $ \ \sim \ $ is an equivalence relation

Comment: if it is given then you can get a contradiction and prove anything you want, making the exercise trivial :o

Comment: Perhaps you should double check whether indeed $d = (-1)^{a-c} b$, and if so then you should rewrite your question to make that correction. Otherwise, this question does not really make sense.